# use nodejs module express-session with secure does not work

Tags: node.js, security, cookies, nginx, express-session

I use express-session module with redis connection and nginx proxy. If I use it with secure: false the sid cookie is set. But if I set it to secure it does not. I am set a other cookie directly with express and secure: true and it works.

Express-Session config in Express:

```
//proxy configuration
app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy (ngnix proxy)

//session

app.use(session({
    secret: 'to-secret-to-show',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    rolling: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'strict',
        secure: secure
    },
    store: new RedisSessionStore({
        client: redis,
        ttl: 86400, //time to life, one day
    }),
}));
```

If secure is set to true or false depents on the envirement. I try to set it directly to true, but does not make a chnage.

nginx proxy settings:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;

        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_redirect off;
```

When I look at Dokumentation files it should be correct. Do I forgot something? I can not make to heavy test, because I have only my live system with secure connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

This is how [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/8e57b21bef0d53010c4d37f4beee3f0341f3eaa6/index.js#L599-L606) determines if the connection to nginx was secure.